# How to replace element with Nokorigi?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have parsed nokogiri document:

```
irb(main):042:0> doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("test <t>123</t> test")
=> #<Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment:0x..fdde2c540 name="#document-fragment" children=[
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x..fdde30c58 "test ">, 
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fdde30834 name="t" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x..fdde36e78 "123">],
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x..fdde30c88 " test">,
   >]>

irb(main):047:0> doc.search("t")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fdde30834 name="t" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x..fdde36e78 "123">]>]
```

How I can replace `Nokogiri::XML::Element` with new `Nokogiri::XML::Text`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449767/find-and-replace-entire-html-nodes-with-nokogiri

Comment: This is not the same. `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment` does not have `create_...` methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new_node=Nokogiri::XML::Text.new("some text",doc)
doc.search("t").first.replace(new_node)
```